# Using unix() to create Unix epoch time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create jalali moment and convert it to unix epoch time ,
Here is my code :

```
  const jalaliMoment = require('jalali-moment')
  let jalaliMoment1=jalaliMoment()

   app.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const jalaliMs = jalaliMoment1.utc(req.body.date).locale('fa').format('YYYY/MM/DD')
    const user =
        {
          date: jalaliMs
        }
    res.status(201).send(user.date)
```

the result in postman is : "1400/02/21"

However , I want to convert this date to unix epoch time.

how I can use unix() in order to save epoch time in my database when I post date?

Comment: `.format('YYYY/MM/DD')` -> `.unix()`?

Comment: if you mean const jalaliMs = jalaliMoment1.utc(req.body.date).locale('fa').unix() I already tried it but not helped!